# Limit number of characters with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking for a way to limit the number of characters for a dynamic box so if there are more than let's say 300, the text will end with ...

Can this be done through AMPscript?

Thanks for your input!
VD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [Substring()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Substring) function:

```
%%[
var @str1, @str2
set @str1 = "1234567890"
set @str2 = iif(length(@str1) > 5, concat(substring(@str1,1,5),"..."), @str1)
]%%
@str2: %%=v(@str2)=%%
```

**Output:**

```
@str2: 12345...
```

Comment: never heard of Length but it seems it's what I need. Thanks Adam!